# How to open a file with special character in their path?

Tags: video-player

I tried to run it from total commander, I tried to make a link to it

```
/media/DATA/#TO_BACKUP/_MUSIC/MUSIC2/Black Eyed Peas - The Time (Dirty Bit).avi
```

but it says

```
Failed to execute child process "/media/DATA/" (Permission denied)
```

Opening the full location from MediaPlayer does not work (open location)

```
Location not found
```

I can open it slowly by navigating in the slow file open dialog, but I would like to open it from totalcmd or by created link or by passing full location.

P.S. Before that I have opened the DATA Partition.

Comment: The answer is not running from wine. You either want the video to run or want to run the video from the wine compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use a media player, like mplayer from console given the location as a parameter, for example

```
mplayer /home/user/myvideo.avi
```

Obviously changing the location of the video

Comment: it works, thx a lot.

Comment: You could also have just escaped the # character with `\#`

Answer (score 0):

Put the path between **quotes**

ex: 
`"/path to/my folder/"`

or put a backslash before the special character

ex:
`/path\ to/my\ folder/`